# Increment Numbers in URL?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, url, numbering

I want to create a list of URLs. The URLs have two sets of identical numbers which need to be incremented by 1:

```
http://sample.com/poilus/cwrgshs/192/192.html
http://sample.com/poilus/cwrgshs/193/193.html
http://sample.com/poilus/cwrgshs/194/194.html
```

I want 192 to be incremented up to 302.

Firefox has an addon called [URL Flipper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/url-flipper/), but it only increments the last number and not both numbers.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? If you just want to print a list with `bash`: `for i in {192..302}; do echo "http://sample.com/poilus/cwrgshs/$i/$i.html"; done`. I smell an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though.

Comment: "I want to create a list of urls". From the shell? PHP? Perl? JS?

Comment: @jw013 Tx! That worked. If you add that as an answer I'll choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: if you just want to print a list with bash:

```
for i in {192..302}; do 
    echo "http://sample.com/poilus/cwrgshs/$i/$i.html";
done
```